# How can we schedule a SSIS job to run every 30 hours?

Tags: ssis, etl, scheduling, jobs

How can we schedule a SSIS job to run every 30 hours , what all properties can be set in the scheduler window ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this via SQL Server Agent and set `occurs every` property. Make sure your previous job completes within specified interval.

[image: img]

Comment: But will it come under 'Daily' frequency ? as 30 Hours is more than 1 day.

Comment: Yes. Read the Description. it says every day, every 30 hours. Means it should get triggered every 30 hours. Nonetheless, do check on dev environment :)